JNDI Connection Issue with mq-jms-spring-boot-starter
I'm using mq-jms-spring-boot-starter
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

I'm strugeling to establish a JNDI connection with the remote IBM MQ Server
Here my service
@Slf4j
@Service
public class JMSService {

    static final String MESSAGE_FORMAT_MQSTR = "MQSTR";


    private String destinationPromoJndiName = "jms/promoQueue";


    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;


    /**
     * Sending a packet via MQSeries to the Promo queue
     */
    public void sendPromoPacket(final byte[] paquet) throws TechnicalException {
        try {
            log.info("send message to  '{}", this.destinationPromoJndiName);
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.destinationPromoJndiName, paquet);
        } catch (JmsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new TechnicalException("error sending promo packet ..");
        }
    }
}

I got the following error
2024-04-16T08:31:02.815Z  INFO 1 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-4] c.package.fr.tpmc.storage.JMSService   : send message to  'jms/PromoQueue
org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'Client'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:274)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:533)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:610)
    ...
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'Client'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:489)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:458)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8683)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8023)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:322)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:242)
    at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6026)
    at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6055)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:452)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:414)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:328)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:243)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:211)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:517)
    ... 135 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 148 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]],3=localhost(1414),4=,5=RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13670)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.access$100(RemoteFAP.java:13202)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1451)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1392)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:391)
    ... 147 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:1414' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket(RemoteTCPConnection.java:932)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1511)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:1013)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:691)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:283)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:170)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:128)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13402)
    ... 153 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:589)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:686)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$4.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1111)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$4.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1103)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.connectSocket(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1103)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket(RemoteTCPConnection.java:838)
    ... 160 more
2024-04-16T08:31:03.590Z ERROR 1 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.package.fr.tpmc.exception.TechnicalException: error sending promo packet ..] with root cause


How to configure correctly IBM MQ with JMS ? Here all the provided properties that I should use
      // connection factory ..
      jndi-queue-factory: jms/prologQF

      hostName: x.x.x.x
      port: 1423
      prologQF_channel: QMX0.SVRC.APPPROMO
      prologQF_queueManager: QMX0
      queueProxy_targetClient: MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ
      queueProxy_ccsid: 819
      promoQueue_baseQueueName: APP.PROMO


Please, any help on how to configure the springboot starter ?
Update
I've added the following JmsConfig

@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(JmsProperties jmsProperties) throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName("x.x.x.x");
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel("QMX0.SVRC.APPPROMO");
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(1423);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("QMX0");
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}


I didn't get any error on application bootstrap, but got the following when trying to send a message to the ibm queue
2024-04-16T10:31:20.862Z  INFO 1 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.package.fr.app.storage.JMSService   : send message to  'jms/queuePromo
org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'jms/queuePrologPromo'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:280)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:533)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:610)
    ...
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'jms/queuePrologPromo'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but IBM MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:513)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1358)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1313)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.access$800(WMQMessageProducer.java:75)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.initialise(WMQMessageProducer.java:900)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.<init>(WMQMessageProducer.java:1288)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createProducer(WMQSession.java:1128)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createProducer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1484)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsQueueSessionImpl.createSender(JmsQueueSessionImpl.java:121)
    at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueSession.createSender(MQQueueSession.java:143)
    at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueSession.createProducer(MQQueueSession.java:248)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doCreateProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1141)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.createProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:628)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$send$3(JmsTemplate.java:612)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:530)
    ... 135 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 150 more
2024-04-16T10:31:22.085Z ERROR 1 --- [tpmc1000] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.package.fr.tpmc.exception.TechnicalException: error sending promo packet ..] with root cause

com.package.fr.tpmc.exception.TechnicalException: error sending promo packet ..

...


I'm not able to register the connection factory java:/jms/queueProlog !

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: nothing is listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

@user207421 because it takes the default configuration. till now I didn't specify any IP:port

I tried to add spring.jms.jndi-name=java:/jms/queueProlog but still confused on how can I use the other properties (like hostname/port ..)

Your question details are unclear - have you created a JNDI entry for jms/queuePrologPromo that refers to the IBM MQ Queue Name APP.PROMO ?

@MoragHughson yes it already exists. I'm trying to connect to the remote server with the provided informations

we don't need the JmsConfig (it should be deleted! ) we only need to add the following configuration in application.yml
ibm:
  mq:
    queueManager: QMX0
    channel: QMX0.SVRC.APPPROMO
    connName: @ip(1423).     # x.x.x.x(1423)

Additinally, for the queue name we should use APP.PROMO instead
It works as a charm (no need for JNDI) ;)

The error message
org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'jms/queuePrologPromo'

suggests that spring is unable to resolve the JNDI name into a queue name.
You should have the following set in your application.properties
ibm.mq.jndi.providerUrl=...
  ibm.mq.jndi.providerContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory


based on the mq-jms-spring-boot-starter docs for JNDI
Failing that you could supply the host and port via application.properties eg.

ibm.mq.queueManager=QM1  
ibm.mq.channel=DEV.APP.SVRCONN
ibm.mq.connName=server.example.com(1414)
ibm.mq.user=user1
ibm.mq.password=passw0rd

as documented in the repo for mq-jms-spring-boot-starter
Failing that you can add the queue name into application.properties. with any key of your choice. eg.
app.queue.name=DEV.QUEUE.1

then inject that into your code. eg.

    @Value("${app.queue.name}")
    public String sendQueue;


